# Unable to start debugging on webserver. VS2010

Tags: asp.net, .net, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am using VisualStudio 2010 for a company-specific project. It was clearly working for a month while I was doing it. and now suddenly it doesn't work. I get this error(shown below) I have tried everything uninstall/reinstall even took the file from its source extract the zip and retry it. Furthermore I have reset my PC (REMOVE OFF EVERYTHING) still I face that problem Help me

[SPECIFIC ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aECP.png)

when I create a new project and run it. It works perfectly but this doesn't idk why. The same file was working previously and now it isnt

Comment: When I get this type of problem, I usually rename the web. Config file to web.config. Bak  then re-run the project which creates a new web. Config file...